# Active Array of Streaming Audio Amplitude

Tags: java, android, audio, streaming

I was wondering if anyone knew how to convert a continuous input into the mic of an Android device into a byte array, or time-amplitude coordinates.  What I want to do is get an array of data so that

> array[time]=amplitude

This must be active, which is one of the major obstacles in my path, as most audio waveform graphers rely on closed files.  Can anyone guide me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any special requirements for what `time` is supposed to be? A PCM stream (which is what you get when using the `AudioRecord` class) is by definition a digital represenation of the input signal's amplitude sampled at regular intervals.

So if you record at 48 kHz mono, each sample in the array of PCM data that you read from the AudioRecord will represent the audio signal's amplitude at time N*20.83 us.